# Evince has the wrong margins when printing a pdf

Tags: debian, pdf, printing, evince

I am running Debian jessie.

When I attempt to print a pdf (on evince), it prints as if the margins are moved over, or the zoom is wrong.

Both of these settings seem correct in actuality, but even the print preview is wrong. Has anyone else experienced this? What can I do to fix it?